# PYTHON Записать число и слово в переменные вывести на экран сначала слово потом переменную через пробел

Tags: python

Вообще не могу понять как это сделать перепробовал уже много способов, поискал на многих сайтах, но найти нужного вроде-бы не смог

```py
s='Да'
d=1
```

Comment: `print(f'{s} {str(d)}')`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
print(f'{s} {d}') #Только Python 3.8 и выше

# или так:

print(s, d)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Никита, только укажите, что так работает в Python 3.8 и выше